# Json path triggers local, but not when published. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .js file that works fine locally, but I am somehow having path problems when I commit and add to my server. I have "Home" for the controller name, and "LoadTable" for the JsonResult function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tableClick').click(function () {
    $.post("Home/LoadTable", $('#FormTable').serialize(), function (data) {
        alert("test");
    }, 'json');
});
});
```

Should I have the path name be something else when published?  If so how do I toggle from local to server version in my webconfig, if possible?

Is there another option?

Comment: where is the `Home/LoadTable` ? i mean under which dir?

Comment: @Val - I'm not sure what a dir is.  LoadTable is in the HomeController.cs file and changes to the function above. Hope this helps.

Comment: do u have firebug ? if u do, look on the net tab and read the error from the request tab

Answer (score 2):

1. /Home/LoadTable  = absolute = example.com/Home/LoadTable
2. Home/LoadTable = relative =   {current_url}/HomeLoadTable

Answer (score 0):

With Val's help, I was able to come up with the following.

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
if (pathName == "/") { pathName = ""; }
$.post(pathName + "Home/LoadTable", $('#FormTable').serialize(), function (data) { 
    alert("test");
}, 'json');
```

Comment: @user54197, please don't come up with this and see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081154/json-path-triggers-local-but-not-when-published-why/5082494#5082494).

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode urls. Always use Url helpers when dealing with urls:

```
$.post(
    '<%= Url.Action("LoadTable", "Home") %>', 
    $('#FormTable').serialize(), 
    function (data) {
        alert('test');
    }, 
    'json'
);
```

Another possibility is to have a link somewhere on your page:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Load table", "LoadTable", "Home", null, new { @class = "loadTable" }) %>
```

which you would AJAXify:

```
$(function() {
    $('.loadTable').click(function() {
        $.post(this.href, $('#FormTable').serialize(), function (data) {
            alert('test');
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```